# How to display ratings in descending order in java code using jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to write a code to display ratings in descending order, but I want like if for example:

I have ratings 1star to 5star, if 1star ratings is 2, 3star ratings is 4, 5star ratings is 1, 2 and 4star ratings is 0 count.

Now I want to display in descending order 5star count, 4star count, 3star count, 2star count and 1star count.

```java
List responseList = new ArrayList();
String lables = "54321";
String present = "";
List<Map<String, Object>> dataList = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

String sql = "select distinct count(name) name, technical from data where name =? group by Technical order by technical desc";

Map dataMap = null;
try {
    dataList= jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql,name);

    for (Map<String, Object> row : dataList) {
        dataMap= new HashMap();

        String technicals = null;
        technicals =  row.get("technical")+ " Star";
        present +=  row.get("technical");
        dataMap.put("count", row.get("name"));
        dataMap.put("technical", technicals);

        responseList.add(dataMap);

        HashSet<Character> u = unique(present,lables);

        for (Character h : u) {
            System.out.println(h);
            dataMap= new HashMap();
            dataMap.put("count", 0);
            dataMap.put("technical", h + " Star");
            responseList.add(dataMap);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For sorting by rank, take a Pojo instead `Map`, it will be easy to customise sorting.
Your POJO should implement comparable interface and should provide `hashcode` and `equals` methods for `technical` field. Here example code. And for sorting `TreeSet` would be better instead `ArrayList`.

```
public class RankCount implements Comparable<RankCount>{
    
    private String technical;
    private int count;
    
    public RankCount(String technical, int count) {
        this.technical = technical;
        this.count = count;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((technical == null) ? 0 : technical.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        RankCount other = (RankCount) obj;
        if (technical == null) {
            if (other.technical != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!technical.equals(other.technical))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RankCount [technical=" + technical + ", count=" + count + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(RankCount o) {
        return o.technical.compareToIgnoreCase(this.technical) ;
    }
 
}
```

Example :

```
    Set<RankCount> dataList = new TreeSet<RankCount>();
    
    RankCount rc1 = new RankCount("3 Star", 4);
    RankCount rc2 = new RankCount("1 Star", 2);
    RankCount rc3 = new RankCount("5 Star", 1);
    RankCount rc4 = new RankCount("2 Star", 0);
    RankCount rc5 = new RankCount("4 Star", 0);
    
    
    dataList.add(rc1);
    dataList.add(rc2);
    dataList.add(rc3);
    dataList.add(rc4);
    dataList.add(rc5);
    
    System.out.println(dataList);
```

**Output:**

```
[
RankCount [technical=5 Star, count=1], 
RankCount [technical=4 Star, count=0], 
RankCount [technical=3 Star, count=4], 
RankCount [technical=2 Star, count=0],
RankCount [technical=1 Star, count=2]
]
```